# Visio shape drop size

Tags: visio

I have custom stencils, and the shapes are all sized relative to each other. I want to know if there is a way to change the size that they drop onto the page? So if I set the multiplier to 1.5 then every shape will drop onto the page 1.5x larger than the master shape specifies. I don't want to have to resize later.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the ondrop cell of the shapesheet.
setf(getref(width), width.thepage!prop.scale)+setf(getref(height), height.thepage!prop.scale)

I wonder however if you wouldn't go better by modifiying the scale of your page directly?

Comment: @Krishna Kuntala, I agree with your suggestion for most of the cases. But I could very well imagine having an application where different sizes matter. Regards